# java dynamic classloader

Tags: java, classloader

how can I dynamically load a class in Java with two parameters which are the absolute filepath of the class file and the name of the method I wish to call?

eg path: c:\foo.class 
   method: print()

I am just interested in the basics as a simple cmd line tool. A code example would b appreciated.

cheers hoax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/LoadClass.html):

```
// Create a File object on the root of the directory containing the class file
File file = new File("c:\\myclasses\\");

try {
    // Convert File to a URL
    URL url = file.toURL();          // file:/c:/myclasses/
    URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

    // Create a new class loader with the directory
    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

    // Load in the class; MyClass.class should be located in
    // the directory file:/c:/myclasses/com/mycompany
    Class cls = cl.loadClass("com.mycompany.MyClass");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
}
```

After this, you could do something like this to first create a new instace using the default constructor and invoking the method "print" without arguments:

```
Object object = cls.newInstance();
cls.getMethod("print").invoke(object);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`URLClassLoader`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html). The name of the method is irrelevant. You must pass the root directory of your package to the class loader. Then you can use the fully qualified class name (package + class name) in `Class.forName()` to get the `Class` instance. You can use the normal reflection calls to create an instance of this class and call methods on it.

To make your life more simple, have a look at [commons-beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/). It makes invoking methods much more simple.