# Best Approach for Executing Jar from within java Application

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that converts the use of a script to a GUI with a button to build something. One of the things that the script does is to load a jar file and run a specific class in this jar with the arguments attached. In the script it is executed like so:

> java -classpath "/path/to/some/classes/" com.company.app.App -i -e

The additional classes in the class path is where the class file being executed is located. This is different for each user of the application.

The approach I've thought of is to build a Process then execute this with the ProcessBuilder class, e.g:

```
List<String> command = Arrays.asList("java", "-classpath", "/path/to/some/classes/", "com.company.app.App", "-i", "-e");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Is there a more pragmatic approach to this inside of java?

Comment: Why not call the `main(String[] args)` method of the class directly?

Answer (score 0):

if you dont need to pass values to the opening program you can use the `Desktop` object, something like:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("/Desktop/jarfile.jar"));
```

simple and easy way that i've found useful many a time. Hope it helps.

edit:- you can check if your desktop is supported as well using

```
if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){ 
//open
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to ask if you really need the loose coupling of dynamically calling the class.  Since the jar is on your classpath, you can just create an instance of the class in your code like you normally would for any class.  This would of course require the jar for the compilation step, but this is normal.

If you decide that you really do need a dynamic call then you should be making the call via JNDI using an InitialContext http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html

Additional JNDI reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/

Comment: The jar isn't in the classpath and will vary in location with where the user puts it we have no standard for this.

Comment: Then this should be done with some sort of dynamic classloader.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790289/java-dynamic-classloader